# In Laravel 8, how to insert data into a configured database in config/database.php?

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-query-builder

In `config/database.php` (Laravel 8) this is configured:

```
'connections' => [
    'my_db' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => 'xx.xx.xxx.xxx',
        'port' => '3306',
        'database' => 'Sqlxxx',
        'username' => 'Sqlxxxx',
        'password' => 'passxxx',
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
   'other_db' => [
        ...
    ],
],
```

I try to save some data, but it doesn't work.

```
DB::connection('my_db')->beginTransaction();

$data = [];
$data["A"] = "a";
$data["B"] = "b";

$pdo = DB::connection('my_db')->getPdo();

if ($pdo) {
    DB::connection('my_db')
        ->table('my_table')
        ->insert($data);
}

DB::connection('my_db')->commit();
```

I specify that the connection to the DB my_db works, because I can get data from it. I have the impression that it can read data but not save them.

EDIT:

- I have multiple connections defined in config/database.php
- my_db is a database outside of my project
- There is no error message; just a blank page (`APP_DEBUG` is set to `true` and `APP_ENV` to `"local"`)
- I added `DB::connection('my_db')->beginTransaction();` to the beginning of the script, to no avail.
- It doesn't work in the following way either: `DB::connection('my_db')->insert('insert into my_table (A, B) values (?, ?)', ['a', 'b']);`
- I'm freaking out. Updating works, inserting doesn't. This works: `DB::connection('my_db')->table('my_table')->where('id', '1')->update(['a' => '111']);`

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and add the error message to it?

Comment: @shaedrich I can't find it! The script returns me a blank page....

Comment: Why you don’t use the seeders?

Comment: Not that it answers your question but I advise you to read the docs on Eloquent. You would be better suited using models instead. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#introduction

Comment: Also, do you have multiple connections defined in `config/database.php`? If not, you don't need to do this at all; simply set the default to `my_db`, then do `DB::table('my_table')->insert($data)`.  Echoing Nuno's comment though, Models can be defined on a per-connection basis; you can set which connection each Model uses, and you then wouldn't have to do the `DB::connection()->getPdo()` stuff at all.

Comment: @NunoPeixoto Sure, I use Models! But my_db is a database outside of my project.

Comment: @marco987 Is `APP_DEBUG` set to `true` and `APP_ENV` to `"local"` in your .env?

Comment: @shaedrich yes.

Comment: @TimLewis Yes, I have multiple connections defined in `config/database.php`

Comment: And you're running this _inside_ of Laravel? If not, you may set `error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: Probably best to include all of these comments as an [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68653922/edit) to your question  The fact we have to ask for so much clarification means your question isn't quite clear enough.

Comment: Have you checked the log file located in storage/logs probably named laravel.log?

Comment: @DanielleCox Yes, no errors reported. I also checked MariaDB log, no error.

Comment: Have you tried using the correct insert syntax? `->insert('insert into my_table (A, B) values (?, ?)', ['a', 'b'])` is wrong; that's raw SQL, which is only really compatible with `->statement()` or `->insert(DB::raw(...))`. Since `->insert()` expects an array of data, the correct syntax would be `DB::connection('my_db')->table('my_table')->insert(['a' => 'a', 'b' => 'b'])`. For reference: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#insert-statements

Comment: @TimLewis What you say is not what the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#running-an-insert-statement) says. Anyway I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: That's the documentation for the `DB` facade's `insert()` method, which is similar, but not quite the same as the Eloquent/Builder version (that I linked). Looking at that though, it should work as you wrote it, unless the `DB::connection()` invalidates it. I try to avoid using those statements anyway, as they're incompatible with multiple database types (MySql, Postgres, etc. have different syntax), where Eloquent/Builder works for all (well, most) DB types.

Comment: @TimLewis Thank you. I will try it out. If it works, I will kindly ask you to write down the answer so I can mark it as a correct and accepted answer ;-)

Comment: I went ahead and added an answer showing the various ways to insert/update/etc. based on Connection; should cover all of your use cases, but let me know if there's any further issues.

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit; your question should remain strictly a question. You are more than welcome to contribute an answer of your own, though (the deleted text is still available from the question's [revision history.)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68653922/revisions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED:** It was my mistake. I was trying to create a new record forgetting to indicate all the NOT NULLABLE ones. I could have figured it out by the fact that the update worked while the insertion did not. I confirm that `DB::connection('my_db')->table('my_table')->insert($data);` works perfectly.

Comment: @TimLewis Before I acted, I made sure the bounty went to you. And it will. I did not directly assign it to you because your response did not resolve the issue. The way I was using it was correct, as you saw. I was just wrong in not valuing all the no-null columns. That being said, the bounty will come to you, because I put Like to your answer anyway, because it helped me reason in some way. But, you will understand, I could not accept your answer as correct. Thank you for your interest!

Comment: Ah, perhaps I'm incorrect in how bounties work; I thought that selecting an answer was the way to assign it (again, not worried about the reward ). If that is not the case, then please disregard most of my comment above. And yes, I understand the reasoning for adding this answer, but generally if the issue was "I made a mistake and didn't handle X", then leaving that as a comment on an existing answer and selecting that is the way to go. That, or closing the question as appropriate (syntax error, non-reproducible, etc etc). Just some food for thought on how Stackoverflow generally works 

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of spots in the documentation on how to do an insert:

1. [The `DB` Facade's `insert()` method:](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#running-an-insert-statement)

```php
DB::insert('insert into example_table values (col_1, col_2), (?, ?)', ['col_1_value', 'col_2_value']);
```

This uses a bound parameterized query to directly insert into the default Connection's `example_table` table. This doesn't appear to be compatible with `DB::connection(...)->insert()`, as the `insert()` method used while chaining is not the same method as above, but rather the Builder's method (see below).

2. [The Query Builder's `insert()` method:](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#insert-statements)

```php
DB::table('example_table')->insert(['col_1' => 'col_1_value', 'col_2' => 'col_2_value']);
```

The Query Builder in Laravel is a Database-Agnostic wrapper for allowing communication with the database based on the driver (MySQL, PostGres, etc.). It expects a simple associative array representation of the columns being inserted, like `['a' => 'a', 'b' => 'b', ...]`, and performs the `insert` based on the supplied or default Connection and specified table (i.e. this **is** compatible with `DB::connection()`).

An additional approach would be to use a Model, with the specified Connection defined. For example, let's define an `Example.php` Model, with the `my_db` connection:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Example extends Model {
  protected $connection = 'my_db';
  ...
}
```

Because we're setting `protected $connection = 'my_db';`, any calls to this model with automatically use the `my_db` connection defined in `config/database.php`'s `connections` array. Examples:

```php
$example = Example::create(['a' => 'a', 'b' => 'b']);
```

This would run `INSERT into examples (a, b) VALUES ('a', 'b');` using the correct database syntax (MySQL, Postgres, etc.). Additional calls to `Example::update()`, `Example::delete()`, etc. would all know to use the proper connection.

I would recommend this approach over the `DB::connection()->table()` method, and would *highly* recommend not using the `DB::insert()` method at all.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't get any errors upon inserting data it seem to be either of two cases:

1. Your transaction somehow reverts
2. Your data doesn't get flushed (only cached somewhere in unit of work or something similar)

Try removing the `DB::connection('my_db')->beginTransaction();` and `DB::connection('my_db')->commit();` statements.